# Why do physics objects freak out when I rescale them?

Tags: physics, transforms, rigid-body-simulation

I was working on my blend project with no regard for scaling until I realized that the physics was incredibly slow due to the actual size of the objects I was working with being giant.

So I thought to rescale everything in my project but this seems to ruin the physics stuff I've created.

I tested it in a new project by rescaling this chain of rigid bodies
(side by side comparison):
[image]

When I run the simulation the rescaled group of objects "explodes" at the beginning, as if it's trying to orient its rigid bodies to where they were before being scaled down:

[image]

Changing the **scene_properties> rigid_body_world> substeps_per_frame** to 1 can result in this sagging behavior instead:

[image]

Is there a way to resolve this issue without having to start from scratch at the smaller scale?

Blend File: [image]

Comment: Have you applied the new scale?  Ctrl + A

Comment: That was the solution to this which I forgot to test.  damn.

My actual problem lies in a file where these physics objects are parented to an armature.
(Ctrl + A) applying the scale to a child of an object does nothing to the child's actual scale. So I dismissed that solution when recreating the new example project.

Guess I'll open another issue to ask that specific question.

Comment: @AllenSimpson I'll mark you as the answer to this question if you post an answer.